# Can't create multiple objects with MongoDB + Node

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack, insomnia

I am trying to create multiple objects with mongodb, mongoose and express (by using Insomnia). I have managed to create the first object, but when I try to create the following one it gives me the following error:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": {
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000
  }
}
```

I tried to solve it by including different data in the object (although I didn't specify uniqueness in the properties), but it will throw the 11000 (duplicate key) error anyways.

The log of req.body returns { inmovilizadoInmaterial: 12, inmovilizadoMaterial: 13 } (as the data included for the registration are those values)

Here's the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const balanceSchema = new Schema(
  {
    inmovilizadoInmaterial: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    inmovilizadoMaterial: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Balance", balanceSchema);
```

Here's the router that connects the model and the controller the object:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const balanceController = require('../controllers/balance.controller');

router.post('/create', balanceController.create);

module.exports = router;
```

And finally here's the controller that has the function that creates the object.

```
const balanceController = {};

const Balance = require('../models/Balance')

balanceController.create = async(req,res)=>{
    const balance = new Balance(req.body);
    balance.save();
}

module.exports = balanceController;
```

I know it must be a very simple mistake but I'm very new to the technology.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you didn't specifically set any uniqueness constrains on any index then the only default constraint is on the `_id` field. i'm assuming you're sending it in the `req.body`.

Comment: Yes, it is included in the req.body. The problem, was that the duplicate key was userId (in an older version of the db it was a property that is not included in here anymore). I didn't know that the data in the db remained after changing the schema, I thought it would be updated when executing the server.  Thank you tho!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your controller like this:

```js
balanceController.create = async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    console.log('Req body:', req.body);
    const balance = await Balance.create(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({success: true});  
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    res.status(400).json({success: false, error});  
  }
}
```

Note that `req.body` will be logged so you can check whether your controller receiving correct data (maybe you are sending empty `req.body` from the frontend). Also `error` will be logged in. If this does not work, add both output of `console.log(req.body)` and `console.log(error)` to your question.

Comment: Nope, same thing. As there's an error (11000) it will always enter the catch of your code. The problem is the second time I try to register information into the db. Literally the collection has 1 item. If I delete it, it will register the new one, but again, only allows one item in the db.

Comment: Yes, but try to `console.log(error)`. It will tell you want `key` is duplicated. Also, please add `console.log(req.body)` to your question.

Comment: The console.log(error) did the trick! The duplicate key was userId (in an older version of the db it was a property that is not included in here anymore). I didn't know that the data in the db remained after changing the schema, I thought it would be updated when executing the server. Thank you very much!

Comment: Noup, all data from before remains. It's just that new data will be created based on updated Schema Model.